# I just got sent to a fake windows tech support website

Tags: virus

And it spam downloaded a bunch of random files. I'm a little worried now, but I know that the people who make these websites are usually very unintelligent. However, can I have some reassurance or a way to prevent the files from causing any harm if they are harmful? Thanks.

Comment: What browser and OS were you using? Did it automatically download them (like Chrome does), or did you manually tell the browser to download them? Did you open or run any of the files after they downloaded?

Comment: I did not run any files, and it auto downloaded. Not manually.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are asking. This situation is exactly what antivirus is for. Do you not trust your antivirus? What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’re using a modern and updated operating system and browser, just delete the files (without opening any), delete them from the recycle bin, change your browser settings to not download files automatically, and run a virus scan. If everything looks normal then you should be fine.